# add custom field in user register form

Tags: user-meta, profiles, user-registration

In my WordPress based site, I want to add a custom field (e.g. type of user - employee, investor) in the user registration form in the **admin side**, **without editing the core file**. Can anyone please suggest how can I do it, may be a plug-in or some script?

I have already tried Cimi, Register Plus, CYC plug-ins but they all give facility to add custom field from front side registration form OR in the user edit form after the user is registered for first time from admin side. Is there any way we can do it in the user register form from admin side?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do both - i.e. add something to the registration form AND have it editable from the admin side, you need to do 2 things.

The first, is add extra user meta (so you can see them from the admin side) and the second is to create a new registration template which hooks into WP's registration process.

There's a great tutorial at:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:MO4DlL7hGQkJ:www.cozmoslabs.com/1012-wordpress-user-registration-template-and-custom-user-profile-fields/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&client=firefox-a

Which covers pretty much everything. Good luck!

Comment: Link is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cozmoslabs.com/wordpress-profile-builder/ the pro version of Profile Builder lets you add user fields directly in the backend (Users>Add New User).

However it won't add those fields in the WordPress registration (example.com/wp-login.php?action=register) if you need that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many plugins to add custom fields in user registration form as well as to their profile.

The best I found and also using on one of my site is "[Register Plus Redux](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/register-plus-redux/)" off course it is free.
I think it would be a better solution for you too.